# Sharepoint Foundation Convert Visio to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, interop, visio

I need to convert a Visio file that is uploaded into SharePoint foundation 2013 to be converted to pdf. This is because foundation doesn't offer Visio services.

The only way I can think of doing this is calling a console application from my asp.net c# code to do this conversion using interop. When I run this exe myself the conversion works perfectly. When the Exe is run by being called from the asp.net c# code I get an exception (An exception occurred).

I believe it is a permissions issue but I just can't seem to solve it.I have given the IIS user account full control to the required folders etc. I have given the console application the following line in app.manifest .Neither seem to work.

I'm stumped. I'm aware that Interop should be avoided when using asp.net but I'm all out of ideas as this seems the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are only part of the equation. Automating MS-Office based solutions in service based scenarios (including asp.net) is challenging to say the least.

Have a look at a similar question on [SharePoint.StackExchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60879/how-to-automatically-convert-the-word-document-into-pdf), which links to a number of solutions that integrate directly with SharePoint and support many different formats including Visio.

Disclaimer: One of the answers in the link refers to a product I worked on so consider me biased.